# Как заключить каждое слово в скобки?

Tags: delphi, строки

Задача, заключить каждое слово в текстовом файле в скобки.

Делаю так:

```
function VSkobki(const s: string): string;
begin
  Result := '[' + s + ']';
end;
```

Вызов функции:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
..........................
  s := VSkobki(s);
.......................
end;
```

Что у меня получается, исходный текст:

> test, test test! test test test (test1)

На выходе:

> [test, test test! test test test (test1)]

А нужно что бы результат был вот таким:

> [test,] [test] [test!] [test] [test] [test] [(test1)]

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например вот так:

```
procedure insertSB(var S:string);
var
    i,start,stop:integer;
begin
    i:=length(s);
    while i>1 do
    begin
      if s[i] <> ' ' then
      begin
        start:=i+1;
        while s[i] <> ' ' do dec(i);
        stop:=i+1;
        if ((s[i]=' ')and(i<>0)) or ((s[start]=' ')and(start<>length(s)+1)) then
        begin
          insert(']',s,start);
          insert('[',s,stop);
        end;
      end;
      dec(i);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: А такой вопрос, если файл 12 мегабайт то выдает ошибку access violation at address в строке while not s[i] <> ' ' do dec(i);. Что это может быть ?

Comment: access violation - это косяки с доступом к памяти. Попытка чтения/записи туда, куда нельзя. Посмотрите на ошибки в режиме отладки.

Comment: Как я только не делала, при обработке файла в 1 мегабайт - ошибка.

Comment: @Татьяна А если в строке нет пробелов? `while (s[i] <> ' ') and (i > 1) do dec(i);`

Comment: @Igor, В вашем варианте заработало. Но если в строке нет пробелов то не заключает в скобки. Вопрос: Можно сделать условие, что бы, если пробелов нет, то заключить всю строку в скобки ?

Comment: @Татьяна `if Pos(' ', s) = 0 then begin s := '[' + s + ']'; exit; end;`

Comment: @Igor, Это условие добавить в код или заменить на условие в коде?

Comment: @Татьяна этот код надо вставить в начало процедуры.

Comment: @Igor, Отлично все заработало! Нет слов, у меня, для того - что бы выразить благодарность!

Comment: Команда insert(']',s,start); довольна затратна, поэтому если нужна максимальная скорость, то (видимо) лучше делать перебор по одному символу с копированием в новую строку (которую заранее нужно сделать подлиннее) Чуть подробнее тут https://imageman72.livejournal.com/12303.html